# Window onbeforeunload event sometimes work and sometimes don't(chrome)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am working on a custom script whose work is to detect the tab/window close
and then perform a wordpress function. Initially, it worked, but now it doesn't.

I have created a function in functions.php and created a js file where my script resides. What I am trying to achieve is, I want to logout the current user when he/she closes the tab or browser window.

Here is my js code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
    var message = 'Important: Please click on \'Save\' button to leave this page.';
    if (typeof event == 'undefined') {
        event = window.event;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: {
                'action':'add_myfunc',
            },
            success:function(data) {
                // This outputs the result of the ajax request
                //alert('data:'+data);
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(errorThrown){
                alert(errorThrown);
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }
    if (event) {
        event.returnValue = message;
    }
    return message;
};    

$(function () {
    $("a").click(function () {
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
    });
    $("input[type='button']").click(function () {
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
});
$("input[type='submit']").click(function () {
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
});
});
```

It sometimes shows the "leave/cancel" prompt but sometimes don't. If anyone can help with this, that would be awesome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't execute asynchronous tasks in `beforeunload` handler. When the function has been executed, the default action (not cancelable) aborts ex. any pending AJAX call. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Beacon_API .